# What happens in AngularJS when doing a hard refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I've come across a pretty strange thing in my angularJS application. The application is just a basic app which consumes a python api back-end via HTTP requests. The app works really good and is really fast whenever you change routes using the navigation. The api responses are almost instantly and the template is displayed. However when i do a hard refresh (cmd + r or via the browser icon) or choose the back-button in the browser it takes around 10-15 seconds to get the data of that route.

I've looked around on the internet but couldn't find a simular problem. Anyone any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: support e-tags on your requests.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Comment: sounds like a bug in your app. do some profiling to see where that time is used

Answer (score 0):

Because after the initial load all the route that you visit are cached by angular , so you will feel that they are loaded quite fast , but when you do a hard refresh that cache get erased.

Comment: new routes are also fast. This behaviour only happens when i refresh the browser or go back via the browser buttons

Comment: It is possible that you have 1 js uploaded to client from server for few pages/routes. So first time you load files and data for all/part of routes.